# How to download tile from Amazon’s Sentinel-2 service

Tags: sentinel-2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sentinel

How do I access Sentinel-2 imagery via Amazon?

I'm new to GIS and have been relying on USGS earth explorer and EO Browser but would now like to access satellite imagery with higher resolution. [I read](https://medium.com/@anttilip/comparison-of-spatial-resolutions-in-satellite-images-3185963a2e96) that I could do so using Amazon’s Sentinel-2 service.

I found this guide https://registry.opendata.aws/sentinel-2/ I have an AWS account - is there a guide for users who have never used Amazon?

The guide for Sentinel-2 L1C says,

```
the files for individual scene are available in the following location: s3://sentinel-s2-l1c/tiles/10/S/DG/2015/12/7/0/
```

Where exactly is that?

To provide a specific example, I'd like to download tiles of central Hong Kong at <10m resolution, anything newer than 2012

```
xmin 114.1399
ymin 22.2708
xmax 114.1835
ymax 22.2930
```

Answer (score 1):

The s3 Link for your sentinel data is the link to an Amazon S3 bucket. That is where the data is stored. Amazon's cloud services can be confusing for beginners and I am far from an expert. You can find info on the S3 concept on the amazon [website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html).

I personally find it hard sometimes to get the info I need within all the details on the aws websites. For me the easiest way to get sentinel data using the s3 bucket is this:

- get a (free) [s3 Browser](https://s3browser.com/)
- create a new bucket in the s3 Browser
- make sure it allows requester pays buckets since that is the case for the sentinel s3 bucket
- you need to setup your aws credentials in the s3 browser at some point for this to work
- if all that worked then in the path field in the s3 browsers's UI you can enter the path to the individual tiles starting with /tiles/../../.. and this thing works like a file browser from here on.